# Basic User Input Validation //need guide

Tags: c#, regex

last time i've asked some guys here about what can i do to validate user inputs in my program. i'm glad there's enough people who have time for newbie in this field. as their suggestions, i am introduced to Regular Expressions. Looping was my first option but doesn't seem to work for some cases. still i'm having a hard time understanding how Regular Expressions works and watching tutorials online, also by following solutions over the net makes it more complex to me. i'm bad at it i admit. i'm almost in my first month of learning c# and hope there's a more beginner approach on how to use Regular Expressions, as i just want to know how can i utilize it to validate user inputs. just for now btw.

so here's the code i,ve gone through this afternoon as i am trying my best on how can i trap users as they're entering wrong value. also to prevent my program to crash.

can someone guide on how to use regex to properly filter user input? the solutions on the net is way nonspecific. i want to filter the name  (whole name) input as well as the valid age (i might try to ask birth dates and derive the age value)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace test_console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("pls input ur name: ");
            string nametxt = Console.ReadLine();
            string namePattern = @"[A-z]$";
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(nametxt, namePattern))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("invalid name!");
                nametxt = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nametxt))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("pls input a name!");
                nametxt = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Console.Write("now input ur age: ");
            int age;
            while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out age))
            { Console.WriteLine("invalid age!"); }

            Console.WriteLine("hi {0}, you are {1} ", nametxt, age);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: So what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: `^[A-Za-z]+$` (one or many letters in `A-Z` or `a-z` range) instead of `"[A-z]$"`

Comment: hi, by that i am trying to filter out all user inputs but that regular expression i made doesn't work. will try these guys solutions later when i got home

Comment: If you are trying to validate names, please don't forget that there are people with names like Libuše, or Jürgen, or Raphaël. 
Limiting the input to a-z might be more restrictive than it should be...

Answer (score 0):

if you asking about *regular expressions*, then *pattern* for name validation

```
 string namePattern = @"[A-z]$";
```

if almost definitely wrong. Now you are looking for a string which *ends* (`$` anchor) by

```
 [A-z] - exactly one character in A..z range
```

if you consult *Ascii table* for `A..z` range you'll find that it has

```
 A,..., Z, [, \, ], ^, _, `, a, ... z
```

characters (note, *unwanted* `[`, `]`, `\`), that's why `123[` is valid name (it *ends* with `[` which is in *valid range*). You, probably want a pattern like this:

```
 string namePattern = @"^[A-Za-z]+$";
```

pattern:

```
 ^          - string start
 [A-Za-z]+  - one or many characters, each in A..Z or a..z range
 $          - string end
```

So, the entire string must contain at least one character and all the characters must be either in `A-Z` or in `a-z` range

Comment: thanks. I'll  try this suggestion! i made the pattern [A-z] because i want the result to be in Uppercase for the first letter of the name. i might just convert the inputs to uppercase of first letter in the result so that the user can input in either all uppercase or all lowercase.

Comment: btw, what does the "+" in the pattern do? im sorry im really new to this. i just know that @"^[A-Za-z]{2-8}$" as the pattern says i can have 8 characters with minumum of 2 characters in the pattern.

Comment: @theREAL. O: If you want 1st letter to be in Uppercase, and the rest to be in lower case with `2..8` letters in total, the pattern will be `^[A-Z][a-z]{1,7}$`

Comment: by that you mean a user must input with first letter uppercase to proceed? i want my program to be more user friendly as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the Code provided above your Regex expression is wrong for Text for example if some one add a space in the name it will detect as not a name .

secondly if you wish to add Regex for Names then add for Age as well .

lastly the question is not so much clear as well kindly give us more detail onto what are you looking for .

Comment: hi, i am really  sorry. im trying to filter out the inputs from user. im asking their name and age. what ive done in name inputs doesn't work. also i my age inputs, it seems that i have to use regex for age as you suggest because it will receive even 9999999 value of age. thanks for letting me know